# Formula or VBA that finds duplicate case entries in a column, then identifies the minimum in other column by case

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm not very good in VBA, so used helper columns for the beginning of my explanation. If you can do all the operations in VBA, feel free to show me how (if not, skip to the next paragraph).

So in column B I have case numbers (ex. 12345, 12346, etc.) that sometimes repeat themselves (e. 12345, 12345). When there is a repetition, I need all of the same case numbers to show the same case status, which match the one which is the least advanced (data in column D). Therefore the first 12345 could be Planning and the next 12345 could be Action. In column E, I would need the both of them to show Planning. For this, I made a table with associations (ex: Table1), where "Planning" would be 1, "Action" would be 2 and so on.

Therefore, my first helper column has the following formula:

`=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(B:B, B3)>1, VLOOKUP(D3, Table1, 2, False), D3), "")`

If the case number has no repetition, it can keep its original value. The results give me something like this:

[image]

While I need it to look like this at the very least:

[image]

So I can change it back to this:

[image]

So how can I determine the minimum by case number and apply this minimum to all the entries with duplicate case numbers? Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: What version of Excel?  And how do you tell which entry is "least advanced"?

Comment: Excel 2010! I've created a reference table where each status is given a number. So the least advanced would be 1, and the most advanced 5. I use VLOOKUP in my formula. Thank you for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for VBA.

If I understand you correctly, you enter a number in Column C that corresponds to the status.

The following formula will return the least advanced status for any duplicates:  (*the table I named `tblStatus`*)

```
=VLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$1:$B$8=B1)*$C$1:$C$8,1),tblStatus,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

**Edit:**

If, as you show in your example, you might have either the status number **OR** the status text in column C, then you need to convert the text to a number in order to use the `MIN` function equivalent.

In that case, try:

```
=VLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$1:$B$8=B1)*IF(ISNUMBER($C$1:$C$8),$C$1:$C$8,MATCH($C$1:$C$8,tblStatus[Text],0)),1),tblStatus,2,FALSE)
```